# How to use Google Cloud OCR for image to text recognition

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, ocr

I will highly appreciate if we can set up here a step by step working example of how to use Google Cloud API services for image to text OCR recognition.
I want to get a text from an image.
As far as I read:
1. You need to set up credentials to use this API which I did it and as result I had to download a file (I hided the real keys & private_key):

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "carcheck-login",
  "private_key_id": "replace with yours",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----replace with yours\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "carcheck@carcheck-login.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "replace with yours",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/carcheck%40carcheck-login.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

But from here what is next? How do I include the php or JS library and where I download it?

I found some functions and sample how to read image here:
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-text#vision-text-detection-php but it is now clear how to use these first 2 lines:

```
namespace Google\Cloud\Samples\Vision;

use Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient;
```

and where to download their libraries..

Please help to add the missing part so this can be used as a working example

Thanks for your time

Comment: Google has documentation, guides, example code on their website. Start there. Google Qwiklabs has a number of vision labs that will walk you thru everything as well. https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr PHP Library: https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.101.1/vision/visionclient

Comment: Thank you John, I read it and still not clear what files I need to include before making the request..

Comment: I recommend going to Qwiklabs and complete their labs. This will walk you thru the entire process.